# Cakephp 3 routing not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am creating a route in cakephp 3.2 under the scope `'/'`. But it is not working.

here is my code.

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('/user/:user',['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'myAccount'],['user'=>'/^[a-z0-9_-]$/','pass'=>['user']]);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
}
```

When I am visiting a URL like `http://localhost/mysite/user/username` then it is throwing an error `UserController` not found.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$routes->connect(
    '/user/:user',
    ['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'myAccount'],
    ['user'=>'/^[a-z0-9_-]$/','pass'=>['user']]
);
```

This route element regex, if it worked, is going to restrict the user parameter to be exactly one character.

To match "username", or any string longer than one char it's necessary to modify the regular expression for example:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/user/:user',
    ['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'myAccount'],
    ['user'=>'[a-z0-9_-]+','pass'=>['user']]
//                      ^             
);
```

Note that [route element regular expressions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements) are not expected to be a complete regex.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day.